# Can i store File chunks in different systems in the IPFS Network?

Tags: distributed, ipfs

I am using IPFS for file storage for my application, I have created a private network swarm of 4 nodes. I assumed initially that the file would be chunked and the chunks will be stored into different devices(Which is my requirement). But I found out that the file will be stored into the local after chunking from this blog [Where does IPFS store all the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450007/where-does-ipfs-store-all-the-data). Now I was wondering if it is possible to chunk the data when `ipfs add filename` and store the chunks on different systems  is possible.
If so how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

IPFS is not a file storage but a p2p protocol.
Files are still stored locally when you do `ipfs add filename` 
Other peers can store your published file by requesting the file then `pin` it.
Instead of thinking about changing the IPFS protocol, what you can do is to build your application on IPFS that behaves as storage such as [filecoin](https://filecoin.io/).

Comment: Okay thanks for the information. I will look into the suggestion about building application.