# Which nodes in IPFS store the new file?

Tags: ipfs

In IPFS, after a new file is uploaded by a node, besides existing on that node, it will also be stored in other nodes. Is there any selection mechanism for determining which nodes will store the file?

In IPFS, after a new file is uploaded, will it only be stored on the node where it was uploaded, or will it be stored on multiple nodes? If it is stored in multiple nodes, is there a mechanism for selecting nodes? Translate this paragraph into English

Answer (score 0):

In `IPFS` (InterPlanetary File System), when a new file is uploaded by a node, it is not only stored on that node but also distributed to multiple other nodes in the network. This distribution process is known as `content addressing`, where files are identified by their content and not their location.

IPFS uses a distributed hash table (`DHT`) to locate and retrieve content. When a new file is uploaded, the file is divided into blocks, and each block is given a unique identifier called a content identifier (`CID`). These CIDs are used to address and locate the blocks in the network.

The selection of nodes for storing the file is determined by the content routing mechanism of IPFS. This mechanism uses the DHT to distribute and replicate content across multiple nodes. When a node uploads a new file, it stores the file on its local storage, and then it announces the availability of the file to nearby nodes in the DHT. Other nodes in the network can then request and store copies of the file based on the content identifier.

The selection of nodes for storing the file depends on the proximity and connectivity of nodes in the network. IPFS aims to store content on nodes that are closest to the content's provider in terms of network proximity. This helps optimize content retrieval and reduces latency. Additionally, IPFS uses a distribution algorithm that aims to evenly distribute content across the network, making it fault-tolerant and resilient to node failures.

Overall, the selection of nodes for storing a new file in IPFS is based on the content routing mechanism, which leverages the DHT and proximity-based algorithms to distribute and replicate the content across the network.

Also check out the [Where does IPFS store all the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450007/where-does-ipfs-store-all-the-data?rq=2)